# Did Stalin's son hide the death of a whole hockey team after a plane crash?

Tags: russia

[According to World Heritage Encyclopedia](http://worldheritage.org/article/WHEBN0021385735/1950%20Sverdlovsk%20air%20disaster), in the Sverdlovsk air disaster of 5 January 1950 almost the entire national ice hockey team (VVS Moscow) died, which was covered up by Vasily Stalin (born Dzhugashvili):

> According to a recent news article, Stalin's son Vasily Dzhugashvili,
> an Air Force commander of the Moscow Military District and the patron
> of the ice hockey team, was afraid of his father's possible reaction
> and of the crash investigation

[This blog](https://medium.com/@pawel.k.pomorski/sverdlovsk-plane-crash-or-how-to-manage-hockey-club-in-soviet-era-f50d65ddc81c) adds incredible details:

> families had no information what happened that day. Corpses were as
> mutilated as hard to identify, so gov’t service buried them in a mass
> grave near crash site. It was known that Joseph Stalin had no
> knowledge about the crash and further Vasily’s roster moves. And it
> was some horror-like expansion draft. VVS had still two days to play
> game at Chelyabinsk, so to avoid people’s or Stalin Sr.’s suspicions
> Vasily completed the team with… players who have the same last names
> as deceased ones. Also, he ordered the press to publish Moscow team
> line combinations or scorers only with last names, unless scorers are
> Bobrov, Vinogradov, Shuvalov. Yuriy Zhiburtovich was replaced by his
> brother Pavel, and in the press he was just Zhiburtovich with no first
> name. Alexander Moiseev was replaced by non-related player with the
> same last name. The other players were also replaced by new players,
> but each time when some of them scored, official press didn’t mention
> his name and credited a goal to notable players. The Moscow team won
> 8:3 and returned to the capital city. At the end of season VVS was
> fourth in team standings, but due to Vasily’s rebuilding offensive
> they have won next three championships.

However, I can't find a better source. I reckon that someone who could google in Russian would be able to confirm it.